# How to exclude ID if there are two duplicate results of id and COD_A combination, select the one that is not NULL?

Tags: mysql

I have this table in MySQL 5.6.36-82.0:

| id | COD_A | COD_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 205 | 6 | NULL |
| 205 | 6 | 2 |
| 442 | 2 | 7 |
| 442 | 7 | NULL |
| ... | ... | ... |

Expected output:

| id | COD_A | COD_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 205 | 6 | 2 |
| 442 | 2 | 7 |
| 442 | 7 | NULL |
| ... | ... | ... |

**In this example I expect to return a select without the row | 205 | 6 | NULL |**

Comment: Maybe using group keyword in MySQL helps you.

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN ,I've tried but it couldn't solve this problem

Comment: I assume that you would want to rephrase your question to something like _"if there are two duplicate results of `id` and `COD_A` combination, select the one that is not `NULL`"_ .  But what if there are more than two?

Comment: @FanoFN, Yes. Thanks for the observation. I made the correction.

Comment: Supposing you didn't know the answer and has to calculate it from raw table, I made an answer and tested it in workbench. But lacking ample testing data, would you kindly test it in your place and give some feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `group by id,COD_A having count(*) >1` to get those rows with duplicate id and COD_A combination. Meanwhile, those lines must have `COD_B is null`.  Finally, exclude the rows matching the above conditions using NOT EXISTS to get the desired rows from the main table:

```
select * from tb t where  not exists 
    (
    select id,COD_A from tb where id=t.id and COD_A=t.COD_A group by id,COD_A having count(*) >1 
    and 
    COD_B is null 
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, cod_a, max(cod_b) COD_B from t group by cod_a order by id asc
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: This statement returns an error as id in the SELECT LIST is not defined in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @blabla_bingo yeah i know,  i'm using online compiler ... another one : `select id, cod_a, max(cod_b) cod_b from t group by id, cod_a having cod_a > 1 order by id asc` (i'm using sql server)

Comment: Ok,I see. I provided a different approach for the author to decide though .If there are more than two dupe id + cod_a combination rows, your statement will get the highest cod_b value , while mine will get all the rows excluding the ones which has cod_b is null. In what situation should the OP use which , I guess the OP will decide : )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE id = 205 AND Col_b <> "NULL" OR id <> 205;
```

This line returns the table you want, there might be a better way to do it but it works.

In general it's not a good idea to have a repeated value in your "id" column since it's your identifier after all.

Comment: This is an example of a larger table, when substituting for something generic SELECT * FROM example WHERE id = id AND Col_b <> "NULL" OR id <> id , didn't work table

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select * from t where id <> 205 or cod_b is not null
```

Incidentally, MySQL 5 is reaching end of life next year. Maybe it's worth considering an upgrade.

Comment: That works when the OP knows what exactly the result is. But he probably does not know the answer and has to calculate it from scratch.